# Incorrect alignment in table of content for a specific heading in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents, alignment

I'm working on a right-to-left document in Word 2010 that uses numbered headings. There are three different customized headings. When generating the table of contents, I notice that alignment of the second level heading is incorrect (all other headings are correctly aligned) while the alignment for this heading is correct in the text itself. Take a look at the following screenshot:

[image]

I have tested a lot of different settings for the style of the problematic heading but the problem still exists. The style of different settings are also very similar, but I don't know why this problem occurs.

Comment: check the tab stops are on the right place in the bad headings. They should be the same in both good and bad headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to overcome the issue:

- Relocate the right aligned tab stop in the TOC 2 style so that it is
  at 1.7cm (minimum) instead of 0.85cm (1.5cm was not quite enough);
- Modify the Multilevel Numbering that is linked to the Heading 2 style
  so that it has a space after the number instead of a tab space, which
  would then make it the same as the numbering that is linked to the Heading 1 and Heading 3 styles.